# Add blur class when modal is shown, remove when modal is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm using Kyle Fox's jquery modal plugin, and I am trying to add a 'blur' class to the body. I am using the following jquery code, but it doesnt seem to work. I placed it right before body closes, but it's not doing anything when I hit the link with the 'toggle' class. If I only use the 'addclass' bit, it does work, but then of course I have no way to remove the 'blur' class.

```
    $(function() {

 $(".toggle").click(function () {
     $('body').addClass("blur");
```

});

```
$('body').click(function () {
    $('body').removeClass('blur');
});
```

});

To trigger the event, Click on the 'meer info' link when you hover on the first round picture above 'kraantje pappie'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening in your code:

1. When `.toggle` element is clicked, the `blur` class **is** actually added to `body` element
2. Instantly after the class is added, it's removed by the second part of the script, as you use `removeClass` when clicking on `body`. When you click on `.toggle` you also click on `body` as a parent element ;)

So, this is done wrong:

```
$('body').click(function () {
    $('body').removeClass('blur');
});
```

Use other selector to change `body` class when the modal is open, e.g. add a close button and attach `click` event to it.

To see if I'm correct, just remove the code above from your page, then try clicking on the first modal-element ("KRAANTJE PAPPIE").

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand what you're saying. It makes sense! Now what I actually want to achieve, is that as soon as the dark overlay (that appears behind the modal popup as soon as it open) is clicked, the .blur class is removed from the body element. So change the second part of my code to this:

 $('.jquery-modal').click(function () {
     $('body').removeClass('blur');
 });

But it doesn't seem to work! Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's a way to go. As additional info, you might find `.toggleClass()` function handy when it comes to adding/removing or switching CSS classes. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the lightning fast response! but unfortunely, for some odd reason, clicking the overlay doesn't remove the class on body! even though I specify the '.jquery-modal' (see my previous comment). Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You are using jquery.modal plugin with `clickClose` set to `true`. It seems the plugin code is triggered before yours: 1) The modal is being closed by the plugin onclick, 2) When it's time to trigger your code, there's no longer an element of class `jquery-modal`, so there's no selector to run on. I'd modify the plugin. Just add your code before the plugin does its job. Take a look at the dummy JS here: http://jsfiddle.net/CBSrf/

Comment: I replaced the code in jquery.modal.js. and the only code in my actual php/html file is $(function() {

     $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $('body').addClass("blur");
  });
});  - But for some reason it is no longer adding a 'blur' class on body when I click on the .toggle selector. So weird!

Comment: This might be again the same issue - some scripts run faster and make others not triggable in some way (like removing the selectors). Play around with the scripts order. E.g. try putting your `blur` class script before you link the jquery.plugin.js etc. You have quite a lot JS there, so this can be tricky. Also, put your scripts before the closing `<body>` tag instead of keeping them in `<head>`.

Comment: I tried changing the order of the scripts - but nothing seems to help. 
I just wonder how some modals like http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ do it. (check the 'blur' modal). I just don't know what I need to fix!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Most probably some conflicting scipts. What I know for sure is that writing a custom modal is really not hard and  gives you more control over the code. I wrote this one some time ago, it's really simple (http://jsfiddle.net/tQtcP/). Maybe you can use it and get rid of the jquery.modal completely. Good luck!